# Which is more suited to JavaScript games development, CommonJS or RequireJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm planning on building a JavaScript, html5, nodejs based game. I know that Nodejs uses CommonJS, however I know RequireJS is a rival of CommonJS which is supposedly better suited to the client. Is RequireJS be a better alternative for my client-side JavaScript?

I've got no experience in either of the APIs yet.

http://requirejs.org/

http://www.commonjs.org/

Comment: Dont use requireJS. Use [browserify](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify) to package client side modules and share node.js modules with the client

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question doesn't really make sense. CommonJS is nothing more than a set of standards for common tasks in Javascript development. RequireJS is an implementation of the CommonJS module system for web browsers. Node is a server side Javascript platform, which implements various CommonJS standards.

In short, Node is used for server side Javascript programming and RequireJS is used for modularising client side Javascript code. You can use RequireJS in Node, as an alternative module system, but that is not its primary use case.

Comment: I'm using JavaScript + html5 for the front-end, Nodejs for the back-end. Socket.io for the communication. Thanks for the info, I read: http://requirejs.org/docs/commonjs.html and thought RequireJS wasn't an implementation of CommonJS.

Comment: RequireJS supports AMD, a module format that is based on the CommonJS format. While not exactly the same, there is enough of an overlap to be compatible, as long as the AMD define() wrapper is added around the CommonJS module. I would say 90% of modules can be converted. Anything that does a dynamic require() call will be a problem. As mentioned, Node implements a module system closer to traditional CommonJS modules. Disclaimer: I am the main developer for RequireJS.